# menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I want to make a menu for the admin side of a website and when I saw the top bar of stubleupon I wanted to make a menu with same style, always on top even when you scroll down, and has drop down items.

here is the link to sumbleupon exemple :
http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/2qQfq3/www.thevirtualpiano.com/
and I am not very good in javascript so if anybody can point me where I can find a resource 
or if there is any jquery plugins that does this work it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use javascript if you didn't want to. 
A navigation you want could be done in CSS only.

But here are my favourites:

- [multi level navigation examples](http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html)
- [38 jQuery drop down](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)